# Structued data in a menu

Tags: html, menu

How do you add url item props in a menu after the first li element. I cant seem to get google to pick up my next item props after the first menu list.

```html
<li itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" id="main"> <a> home</a>
    <ul id=" subnav" =""="">
      <li> <a itemprop="url" href="">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a itemprop="url" href="">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a itemprop="url" href="">Item 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="two">
    <a>hello</a>
    <ul id="subnav1">
      <li><a href="">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a itemprop="url" href=""> Item 4 Not being picked up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```